# Inserting values into grails createlink params on page creation

Tags: grails, parameters

I've got a list view and for each line I want a link to another list view showing the related results.  The createlink line I've finally managed to construct looks like this

```
<a href="${createLink(controller : 'RunResults', action:'ListSpecific', params:'[id:testExecQueueInstance.id]')}">my link</a>
```

This generates the link

```
http://localhost:3278/FARTFramework/runResults/listSpecific/testExecQueueInstance.id
```

I know that testExecQueueInstance.id is 22 and I want the link to actually look like this

```
http://localhost:3278/FARTFramework/runResults/listSpecific/22
```

What am I missing?

The idea is that I then have a controller like so which should then list those items matching that id...

```
def ListSpecific(int id){

    render(view: "list", model: [runResultsInstanceList: RunResults.findAllByTestExeQueueID(id, [sort:"testExecTime", order: "desc"]), runResultsInstanceTotal: RunResults.count()])
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using an apostrophe on map of params.
You should try this.

```
<a href="${createLink(controller : 'RunResults', action:'ListSpecific', params: [id:testExecQueueInstance.id])}">my link</a>
```

enjoy.

Comment: Dammit I knew it'd be something obvious after spending an hour wrestling with it lol!  Cheers! :)